# Check web server is up or down in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I need a little help here!!!

If string 'url' contains the address to web server, how do i check whether my web server is up or down?
I got some codes to check Internet connectivity. But even if we have internet connectivity how do we know server is up or not? Is there any better way to do that?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a request,

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                       timeoutInterval:20.0]; 

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest
                                                        delegate:self];
```

Now if you implement (along with all other delegate methods)

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

you will get either succes or error.

Answer (score 2):

Post a request, get the response. If you get a response, the server is up, if not its down..

Comment: i mean how do we do it?? I am new to iPhone programming.

Comment: You can make use of ASIHTTPRequest. Check this link http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

Comment: If you are new to SO, please keep in mind to vote up and accept the answers that helped. It will only help you to fetch more answers in the future

Comment: I think ASIHTTP lib is gaining more popularity over the native NSURLConnection. +1.